# Выделение атрибута html и его перенос

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Здравствуйте. Есть отрывок кода html, редактирую в Sublime text 3.

```
        <input class="button-class-material" id="roll_mater_291" type="radio" name="catalmat_roll" value="3" />
            <label class="drinkcard-cc" for="roll_mater_291"><img class="obrazci_tkan" src="/d/402010/d/rolls_calc_291.jpg" width="65" height="65" data-tooltip="Альбион бежевый"></label>
    <input class="button-class-material" id="roll_mater_292" type="radio" name="catalmat_roll" value="3" />
            <label class="drinkcard-cc" for="roll_mater_292"><img class="obrazci_tkan" src="/d/402010/d/rolls_calc_292.jpg" width="65" height="65" data-tooltip="Альбион белый"></label>
    <input class="button-class-material" id="roll_mater_293" type="radio" name="catalmat_roll" value="3" />
            <label class="drinkcard-cc" for="roll_mater_293"><img class="obrazci_tkan" src="/d/402010/d/rolls_calc_293.jpg" width="65" height="65" data-tooltip="Анаконда белый"></label>
```

Вопрос: как в Sublime text 3 можно массово переместить строку data-tooltip="названия" в свой label после класса class="drinkcard-cc"

Comment: Регулярными выражениями. [**Вот так**](https://regex101.com/r/yCpsO0/1) Вы хотели заменить? Спасибо.

Comment: А нет, не так, похоже. Приведите, пожалуйста, 1 пример желаемого результата. Спасибо.

Comment: MaximPlotnikov, я посмотрел — [**в моём примере**](https://regex101.com/r/yCpsO0/1) вроде так, как Вам нужно. Или что-то не так? Спасибо.

Comment: да, вроде всё так. А средствами sublime text 3 возможно так сделать, либо какой плагин может есть ?

Comment: MaximPlotnikov: **1)** Если нужна замена в одном файле, нажмите `Ctrl+H`, затем `Alt+R` — это включает регулярные выражения. Напротив `Find What:` вводите `(<label class="drinkcard-cc")(.*?)(data-tooltip=")(.*?)(")(><\/label>)`, напротив `Replace With:` — `\1 \3\4\5\2\6`. Далее `Enter`. // **2)** Если нужна замена в нескольких файлах — нажимаете `Ctrl+Shift+F`, затем `Alt+R`. Напротив `Where:` вводите папки, в которых собираетесь производить замену. В остальном то же самое, что и в п.1. // О подробностях см. [**здесь**](http://www.sublimetext.ru/documentation/find-and-replace). Спасибо.